# code prints True only in alphanumeric case but it was supposed to print True in all the cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

so, the problem says, when we input any string, then the output must return True if it is True for the cases that are given below else return False.
cases are: check whether the input string is alphanumeric, has alphabets, has digits, has lowercase alphabets, has upper case alphabets.

I tried `qA2` as an input string.

```
def anum(string):
    if s.isalnum():
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
def alpha(string):
    if s.isalpha():
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
def digi(string):
    if s.isdigit():
        return 'True'
    else:
        return "False"
def lcase(string):
    if s.islower():
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
def ucase(string):
    if s.isupper():
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
```

actual output: `true,false,false,false,false.`

expected output: `true,true,true,true,true.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `any()` operator along with `for` to check above conditions are valid or not for your string.

for loop checks if letter satisfies the condition in the strin and creates a generator.

In your case line  `if any(i.isalpha() for i in string)` will first evaluate `(i.isalpha() for i in string)` and create a generator (if you convert it into list it will be like `[True, True, False]`).

`any` operator will check if if any values in the list if True if yes then it evaluates `if` condition as `True`.

```
def anum(string):
    if any(i.isalnum() for i in string):
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
def alpha(string):
    if any(i.isalpha() for i in string):
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
def digi(string):
    if any(i.isdigit() for i in string):
        return 'True'
    else:
        return "False"
def lcase(string):
    if any(i.islower() for i in string):
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
def ucase(string):
    if any(i.isupper() for i in string):
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
```

Comment: @lokeshbihani I have added explanation. If it helped accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since it checks entire string in order to decide the type of input its saying the given input is alphanumeric

```
try giving 
s[1].isupper()
output:
true

s[2].isdigit()
output:
true
```